# How to create SonarCloud projects using web API?

Tags: sonarcloud

I tried create project with Web-API as described bellow,
`curl -v -X POST https://sonarcloud.io/api/projects/create -d "name=test&project=test"`
but I got a message;
`"Insufficient privileges"`

I wonder it's authority problem, but I don't know how to describe.

I'm using SonarCloud with github account, I'v set a token and created an organization.

referred this document;
https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects/create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `organization` paramater in your request.
([Official documentation](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/projects/create) don't have any description for `organization` paramater. why?:( )

I could create a project through REST API as following command.

`curl -v -X POST https://${TOKEN}@sonarcloud.io/api/projects/create -d "name=kaakaa-test&projet=kaakaa-test&organization=${ORGANIZATION-NAME}"`

`TOKEN` can be generated in ["MyAccount > Security"](https://sonarcloud.io/account/security).
`ORGANIZATION-NAME` is the name of an organization that you belong. When you signup sonarcloud.io by your github account, the organization named `${GITHUB-NAME}-github` was created.

I suppose that your request without `organization` parameter tried to make a project in `default` organization, but you did't have appropriate permission to `default` organization.

**NOTE**: The projet that has `project=test` is already exists, so you cannot create it.

Comment: Only correction is that there is a typo for key "project". Also one can generate token from sonarqube account > security